# Translation not working well

Tags: language

I have crated 2 store views one for each languages, in first sight all looks ok when you change language it works but when you leave that page or click detail view of product it shows the default language. Any solution ?

Comment: Did you implement the product links on your own? Maybe the link to the other store-view?